# Rails - Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Up until yesterday my RoR app was running perfectly fine... but when i logged into the system and run the app i got the error.

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (connection to server at "3.109.111.41", port 5432 failed:
 Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060) 
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?):
```

Solutions i tried

1. restart the postgres services in Services.msc.
2. add host and port with different encoding in database.yml

```
development:
  <<: *default
  username: postgres
  password: qwerty
  encoding: UTF-8
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
```

My database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: purchase_order
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 10 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  username: postgres
  password: my_db_pass
```

logs

```
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2023-01-20 15:52:56 +0530

ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished 
(connection to server at "3.109.111.41", port 5432 failed: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
):

activerecord (6.1.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:83:in `rescue in new_client'
activerecord (6.1.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:77:in `new_client'
activerecord (6.1.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:37:in `postgresql_connection'
activerecord (6.1.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:882:in `public_send'
activerecord (6.1.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:882:in `new_connection'
activerecord (6.1.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:926:in `checkout_new_connection'
activerecord (6.1.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:905:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'        
activerecord (6.1.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:866:in `acquire_connection'
activerecord (6.1.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:588:in `checkout'
activerecord (6.1.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:428:in `connection'
activerecord (6.1.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1128:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (6.1.7) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:327:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (6.1.7) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:283:in `connection'
activerecord (6.1.7) lib/active_record/migration.rb:611:in `connection'
activerecord (6.1.7) lib/active_record/migration.rb:606:in `build_watcher'
activerecord (6.1.7) lib/active_record/migration.rb:588:in `block in call'
activerecord (6.1.7) lib/active_record/migration.rb:587:in `synchronize'
activerecord (6.1.7) lib/active_record/migration.rb:587:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.1.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (6.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:29:in `call'
web-console (4.2.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:132:in `call_app'
web-console (4.2.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (4.2.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `catch'
web-console (4.2.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (6.1.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `call_app'
railties (6.1.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.1.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (6.1.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:37:in `tagged'
activesupport (6.1.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `tagged'
railties (6.1.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.4.2) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:26:in `call'
rack (2.2.4) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (6.1.7) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:148:in `call'
webpacker (5.4.3) lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:25:in `perform_request'
rack-proxy (0.7.2) lib/rack/proxy.rb:67:in `call'
railties (6.1.7) lib/rails/engine.rb:539:in `call'
puma (5.6.5) lib/puma/configuration.rb:252:in `call'
puma (5.6.5) lib/puma/request.rb:77:in `block in handle_request'
puma (5.6.5) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:340:in `with_force_shutdown'
puma (5.6.5) lib/puma/request.rb:76:in `handle_request'
puma (5.6.5) lib/puma/server.rb:443:in `process_client'
puma (5.6.5) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:147:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

I have stuck in this for hours.. Any help will be highly appreciated

Thank you...!!!

Comment: your database.yml says "localhost" but the logs show server at 3.109.111.41. where is the pg location?

Comment: I Actually running in windows...My PG Location is "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL"

Comment: so the postgres server is running?

Comment: Yes...definitely I'm 100% sure...!!! I've create another rails app with same database config... but somehow that seems to be working fine... I've even created a database and create a record and store in db. everything works
`default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: post
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 10 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  username: postgres
  password: db_pass`